# How to make remember flask user choices and not refresh template?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am coding a chatbot. I explain you all from the beginning:

1. Run the python flask code
2. Go to localhost in browser
3. Click on chat with me icon. Select a specific radio button in chatbot pop up window and click start the chat
4. Ask a question to the bot
5. The bot delivers the answer, however the pop up window closes and i must again click chat with me icon, select the previous radio button in order to see the answer of the bot.

The problem is flask renders the template from the beginning without remembering the choices user made before. I have tried e.prevent default but did not work.

Here is some of my code:

```
    @app.route('/')
     def home():
     return render_template('index.html')

    @app.route('/',methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def predict():
      if request.method == 'POST':
      messages = request.form['message']
       .
       .
       .
       return render_template('index.html',bot_message=my_prediction, user_message = messages)


     if __name__ == "__main__":
         app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4000, debug=True)


    <div class="row">                  
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form id="radioform" name="radiobutton" method="POST">
            <input id="faqact" type="radio" value="faqact" name="radiobutton">
            <label for="faqact" type="button">Ask a question or something.</label>        </form>
            <!-- <button id="faqact" onclick="faqact()" type="button">I just want to ask a question</button> -->
            <input id="alexact" name="radiobutton" value="alexact" type="radio">
            <label for="alexact" type="button">I want to make the BOT do something for me!</label>
            <input id="connectact" name="radiobutton" value="connectact" type="radio">
            <label for="connectact" type="button">I want to connect to a human asap!</label>
            
        </div>

<div class="chat-body hide">
    <div class="chat-bubble you">Welcome to our site, if you need help simply reply to this 
    message, we are online and ready to help.</div>
    <div id="me" class="chat-bubble you" value="{{user_message}}"> {{user_message}} </div>
    <div id="bot" class="chat-bubble me" value="{{bot_message}}">{{bot_message}}</div>
```

I guess the solution is pretty simple for those with advanced knowledge. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You could return JSON data from flask and use javascript to update the page.

Comment: Maybe use fetch instead of reload the page: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/javascript